# Class videoThumbnail for found in laravel

Tags: laravel, video-thumbnails

i'm using pawlox/video-thumbnail but got error 'Class not Found'.

this is my Gallery controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Gallery_model;
use App\Gallery_image_model;
use App\Search_index_model;
use DB;
use File;
use Storage;
use URL;
use Image;
use Mail;
use VideoThumbnail;
```

this is my config/app.php file 
in providers array i do

```
Pawlox\VideoThumbnail\VideoThumbnailServiceProvider::class,
```

in aliases array i do

```
'VideoThumbnail' => Pawlox\VideoThumbnail\Facade\VideoThumbnail::class
```

i publish package config file also but still got error..

Comment: make sure you run `php artisan config:cache` command if caching enabled

Comment: Also `composer dump-autoload`